# Remove "Declaration of ... should be compatible with ..." in Laravel in production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, signature, production

I created an APP and removed this error in development. In the app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php class, before the declaration of the class I included the following line:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
```

WHen I send to production and enable the errors display, it gives me two errors:

2/2:

> The Class myApp/.../ClassNameController does not exist

1/2:

> Declaration of ... should be compatible with ...

So I believe the first error is creating the second. The production environment is ignoring the line I added to allow multiple signatures for the same method name.

How can I disable it in production mode?

Comment: "The production environment is ignoring the line I added to allow multiple signatures for the same method name." Your first line doesn't allow anything, it just suppresses error-messages.

Comment: Yes. So how can I omit errors like that in Production?

Comment: Setting your environment to production should disable errors by default